# Is it possible to load a .gpx track on a device to test a tracker with appium?

Tags: python, automation, automated-tests, appium, pytest

I'm using Python on Appium to perform some automatic tests on an application that can track the user when he moves.

Now, I would like to perform some test to the tracker. Normally, to pass this test the developer goes out the office and walks for a while. He also tests if the camera work with the tracker, background mode, etc.
I don't care (for now) about the collateral tests that the tracker could lead me, only if it's possible to test the tracker itself.

The only thing I though it can work is loading in some way a .gpx or .kml file to the device and check if it automatically follows the track and save it correctly.

**How could I make this?**
Also, please let me know if there's a better way to test it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there is no implemented way to send a gpx or kml file using Appium at the moment, my approach here would be to use Appium's *[setLocation()](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/geolocation/set-geolocation/)* function with a twist, as you could loop through the values of your gpx or kml and set the location for each point, using a delay if needed.

Comment: Yes! it worked that way! I took some latitudes and longitudes from a .kml and made an array of positions and a loop that runs it with the setLocation(). You save me man!